# how does ubuntu resolve remote address using loopback nameserver?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Confused about how my ubuntu desktop machine will resolve remote address with loopback ip adrress (127.0.0.1)

My dns lookup file look like this

etc/resolv.conf nameserver 127.0.0.1

I searched through folders host, network manager ,dhcp,network (can't find ip linking to my modem ) But i already used nm-tool, it shows the dns as 192.168.1.1 .

Is there any file pointing my router gateway(192.168.1.1) in /etc folder

Comment: This should probably be migrated to the askubuntu site.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses a local caching DNS server called dnsmasq. By specifying 127.0.0.1 in / etc/resolv.conf applications will communicate with dnsmasq instead of directly with upstream servers. dnsmasq communicates with the recursive resolver found through DHCP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,I am able to figure out that  ubuntu uses local dns (DNSMQ) to resolve the address quickly as possible . I cant line pointing my gate way (192.168.1.1) in dnsmq or dhcp settings either . which file will it lookup after dnsmq .... First browser search cache ,if found it will load pages through it , if not found it will move on to /etc/hosts '127.0.1.1 ' which will check is there any our own apache server created then it will load my website ,if not found .. what will be the next step . which file will ubuntu look